# TopoJSON map not rendering properly using D3

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I've downloaded [this map of Great Britain and Ireland](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/custom/gb-all-ireland) from [Highcharts](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) and converted from GeoJSON to [TopoJSON](http://www.lenart.pl/assets/codepen/gb_all_ireland_topo.json) format (`topojson -o input output`) but it just renders as a black box. I'm following the [famous 'Let's make a map' tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/):

```
var container = d3.select( "#container" );

var margin = 20,
    width = parseInt(container.style( "width" )),
    height = parseInt(container.style( "height" ));

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(50);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("http://www.lenart.pl/assets/codepen/gb_all_ireland_topo.json", function(error, gb) {
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.feature(gb, gb.objects.gb_all_ireland_geo))
        .attr("d", path);

});
```

http://codepen.io/znak/pen/rVYbNB

I've previewed my [TopoJSON](http://www.lenart.pl/assets/codepen/gb_all_ireland_topo.json) file with http://jsoneditoronline.org and found the relevant object containing geometries (I think) but it doesn't work.

My ultimate goal is to visualise an interactive (administrative) map of GB & I. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first spot of bother is the download from Highcharts--it seems to be in a projection that is not wgs84. So the coordinates given are not latitudes and longitudes. If you look at the beginning of highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/gb-all-ireland.geo.json you'll see a few "crs" keys, and mention of "EPSG:7405".

You can convert to wgs84 several ways, including:

```
ogr2ogr -f geojson eire_4326.geojson gb-all-ireland.geo.json -t_srs epsg:4326 -s_srs epsg:7405
```

You could then convert to topojson and pick up where you left off.

It's also important to realize that small changes in the scale and center values of the d3 projections can have big impacts.

If you're not tied to Highcharts, it's probably better to get data that's already in wgs84, like http://www.naturalearthdata.com/ or even use a more comprehensive library and data like mapsense https://developer.mapsense.co/tileViewer/. (Disclosure: I work at mapsense.)

Comment: I don't have to use Highcharts, I just had hard time finding administrative map of GB to use with D3 (so just one level deeper than in Mike Bostock's tutorial). I have downloaded 1:10m Admin-1 vectors from Natural Earth but can't figure out how to convert them to JSON, with only GBR and IRL included. As for Mapsense, how would I display just GB? Thanks.

Comment: So I have reprojected the Highcharts maps to WGS84 and was able to view the map and data on http://converter.mygeodata.eu/. But it still is a black box in D3.

Comment: Looks like highcharts scales the coordinates to something irregular. Got the counties from http://www.gadm.org/  Mapsense currently has US counties so far--maybe all countries soon.